# unable to turn on wifi in backtrack 5 r3 while booting from usb

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, boot, backtrack

i have hp pavilion 15 with RT3290 802.11bgn WIFI-ADAPTER
in my laptop there is a shotcut key to turn on(white light)/off(orange light) wifi which works perfectly on windows.

i installed backtrack 5 r3 on usb drive to use it as a live usb,
but while booting in bt5 i cannot use my wifi as its not turning on.
The indicator is constantly showing orange light(as it is switched off).
Due to this airmon-ng shows nothing like wlan0().

please tell me how to switch on my wifi in backtrack as soon as possible.

Comment: did you ensure that Backtrack has drivers for your WiFi card included/installed?

Comment: how to know that?

Comment: that solution is for intel wifi adapters, he has a Ralink chipset.

Comment: @almonte do you have any solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands will allow you to download, compile and install the latest version of the driver. Since these are backports, they work on any Linux kernel.

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
 wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/10/18/backports-20131018.tar.gz 
 tar xvfz backports-20131018.tar.gz
 cd backports-20131018
 make defconfig-wifi
 make
 sudo make install
```

Comment: so i have to just copy paste these commands on terminal

Comment: Yes. Plus, since I forgot you are on BT, you do not need the "sudo".

Comment: what if i download the file on windows from the link given in command?

Comment: its only of 12MB.

Comment: You may very well download it to Windows, no problem. Then you will have to move it to BT. Try doing it through a shared folder. And yes, it 13M, you are right. Trust me, it's enough. :-)

Comment: ok i've downloaded it on windows, now please tell me the command of bt terminal and where should i save that file in order to access it in bt5?

Comment: You must learn how to "Share a folder" between host and guest. You may Google it. Then you put the file you downloaded in the Shared folder, and start your VM.

Comment: but i m not using VM

Comment: Right. Then just copy it to a folder (any folder) on your USB key.

Comment: not working and i am facing one more problem when i shutdown bt5  the laptop does not shutdown completely and screen goes blank nothing happens next so everytime i have to switch it off from power button

Comment: This has nothing to do with your driver. What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Do you know that in BT you have to configure wifi yourself? In other words: do you know that you have to use wpa_passphrase, wpa_supplicant, and dhclient (if you are linking via DHCP, otherwise you have to learn how to set up a static IP for wifi)?

Comment: i mean that wifi is still off, in other words airmon-ng is not detecting my wifi chipset

Comment: try ifconfig wlan0 up, or whatever your wifi card is called.

Comment: "Device not found"

Answer (score 0):

When the drivers arent pre-installed in the systems library (aka compatible), it is very complex to explain how to install the drivers for your specific wireless card..

See these:
http://back-track-linux.blogspot.com/2012/10/backtrack-wireless-cards-compatibility.html

Like I said, theres a lot of instructions that go into something like this.. sorry.

Comment: Ok here, try this.. worked for that guy:

[RALINKBACKTRACK](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104690)